# Why can't I assign a cookie property value after res.send()?

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

Initial assignment (from a different callback function):

```
req.session.user = 'user1';
```

Callback in question:

```
app.get('/demo', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.session.user);
    req.session.user = 'user2';
}
```

Expected response on calls 2,3,4...

```
req.session.user = 'user2';
```

Actual response on calls 2,3,4...

```
req.session.user = 'user1';
```

I understand that you cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.

With that being said, if I'm accessing `req` and not `res`, why doesn't the actual outcome match the expected outcome?

Comment: @esqew What I'm trying to accomplish doesn't necessarily modify the the `req` object per se, but rather the cookie property associated with it.

Comment: @esqew With all due respect, I think you are missing the point of the question, which has to do with altering server-side express-session cookie properties after res.send() is called. These types of cookie properties are set using the syntax shown in the original post.

Comment: My mistake - misinterpreted your framework use. I've deleted my comments.

Comment: Try setting session before sending the response, for  a moment

Comment: @JKK I've already concluded that works experimentally. What I'm asking is why it's necessary–technically.

Comment: That could happen if cookie change when you update the session. Cookies changes are send alone with the response. See headers from chrome dev tools to make sure